# How can I check connection to node of a cluster before putting a entry to cache?

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan

We use Infinispan 4.2.1 for organization a cluster which consist of two nodes. We need check connection of another node before put a entry into cache. How can I do this?

Comment: Infinispan does not have any 4.5.1 release, do you mean 4.2.1?

Comment: Yes of course, I made the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by this way:

```
JGroupsAddress myAddress = (JGroupsAddress)getInstance().cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getAddress();
List members =getInstance().cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getTransport().getMembers();
            if(members != null && members.size() > 2) {
                for(JGroupsAddress member : (List<JGroupsAddress>)members) {
                    if(!member.getJGroupsAddress().equals(myAddress.getJGroupsAddress())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for all members of the cache:

```
cache.getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getMembers()
```

For a cluster with nodes A and B this will return a list with

```
[A-44188, B-8820]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but we use a old version of Infinispan and we can't use this method. Are there other methods for solve the problem?

Comment: @siom, maybe by chance you know why `getRpcManager()` could return null even if clusters are setuped?